# String resources in C# project

Tags: c#, .net

I have looked into some assemblies of microsoft using decompiler. I have found "Resources" folder in every assembly. and they have some values. But i didnt found any reference of this values in assembly code. 
  Could you anyone tell me why we used resources? and why i didnt found resourcename in anywhere in decompiled code.

[image]

You can see that I have selected System.Data.Entity.Design.resources is selected which is laid under the "Resources" named folder.
What is the use of these name - value pair in the assembly? that is my question. and where this name -value pair is used in the code?

Comment: It's right there in your illustration.  It is a list of name-string pairs.

Comment: yes, I know that. This is snapshot of the decompiler. you can see that I have selected System.Data.Entity.Design.resources is selected which is laid under the "Resources" named folder.
What is the use of these name - value pair in the assembly? that is my question. and where this name -value pair is used in the code?

Comment: They are used for error messages.  They are stored as name-value pairs because you can change the error message without changing the name.  This can be useful if you want to localize, i.e. use a different language for the messages.

Comment: I presume this is something to do with localisation?

Comment: okay...
And where these names are used as variable or something in code in the assembly.? I can't found them in the code.

Comment: They don't *have* to be used at all.  Only when there's an error.  They're most likely used in an assembly you haven't decompiled yet.  If you want to look for them, look for the names in places where exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource strings are loaded by name (like [ResourceManager.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk.aspx) ), so it not necessary to find complete string name in source code. Also strings could be used by some other assemblies too.

I.e. resource:

```
Message_BadOne -> "Bad things happened"
Message_Cool -> "Soo cooooll"
```

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine(resourceManager.GetString(
       "Message" + (isItCool? "_Cool" : "_BadOne"));
```

Comment: Can u tell me why such a code as given you an example is not found in System.Data.Entity.Design.dll?

Comment: No idea. Disassembling non-trivial code is not necessary the best way of learning. Consider looking at some original source instead (parts of CLR as "Rotor", MVC are open source). Note: If you explain what you want to achieve in your question in addition to your immediate question people would be able to provide better answers.